# What are the techniques for debugging angular components that are not displaying on the screen?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and angular material I have very simple view

```
<div class="mat-headline">Product Inventory Search</div>

<form (ngSubmit)="search()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Product</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="product"  />
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

When it display I do not see any input field as seen blow
[image]

If I remove the `form` element surrounding `mat-form-field` like below

```
<div class="mat-headline">Product Inventory Search</div>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Product</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="product"  />
  </mat-form-field>
```

It works I can see the product field as show below
[image]

Two questions:

- How is an angular material input field placed inside a `<form>` element
- When something is not showing up on the screen what tools does angular offer to debug the cause. In my case I see no error message just that the component is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out after a lot of stumbling in the dark and on blog sites.

For each form element on the from angular expects there to a `FromControl` object to store the state of the form element. If there is no `FormControl` angular 10 is not rendering the form element since it has no place to manage the state of the element. There are two ways to create the form controls.

- **Template Driven** where angular creates the `FormControl` objects
- **Reactive** where the developer must create the `FormControl` in the component class

In the case of a reactive form there can be multiple form elements therefore a `FormGroup` object must be built by the developer and associated with form. The code below works.

```html
<form [formGroup]="searchForm"  (ngSubmit)="search()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Product</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="product"  />
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-button color="primary">search</button>
</form>
```

The main change from my incorrect version is the `[formGroup]="searchForm` and `formControlName="product"` instead of `[formControl]="product"`

My misunderstanding of things is now cleared up but I am still looking for ways to more effectively debug issues like this in the future.